# FlowRouter locally served images break after redirect

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

While using FlowRouter if I load my page any locally served images (images/myImage.png) works fine. But if I navigate to a page and then navigate back (home page -> about page -> home page) the image is broken. However in the developer console, if I hover over the image source, the image appears fine.

This is not an issue with images served from another server.

**Update**
I never solved this issue, but because this still seems to be an issue with many people. I'm posting my work around. Based on the Meteor communities advice, I switched to cloud based image hosting like Cloudinary or AWS

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the exact same issue! Even after meteor update

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are sometimes accessing images using their file paths. With Meteor, to serve static files properly, they need to be in the `/public` folder of your project. So you should put them in `/public/images`, and then reference them according to the following example:

The file

`/public/images/foo.png`

is displayed by

`<img src="/images/foo.png>`

See here: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories

Comment: Currently they are in public/images/myimage.jpg . I'll pretend public to my image path later tonight. Although I though that wasn't news. But I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Yea I double checked the paths and also the folder structure, everything seems set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that although my images worked with the following:

**Image is in /public/images/name.png**

```
<img src="images/name.png">
```

But then I changed the url to:

```
<img src="/images/name.png">
```

Now it works and doesn't break.